# How to DIY a anti static bracelet or ground oneself?

Tags: grounding, diy, antistatic

My laptop battery inflates and no longer works. I buy a new one and plan to install it myself, but I don't have an anti-static bracelet. I don't want to shock my laptop with statics. Is it possible to DIY one or DIY ground myself? Like maybe use a wire to connect my skin and a nail on wall, or just don't wear shoes and touch ground with feet? I was even once told that if we wash hands because water connects to water tap, which connects to wall, we eliminate our statics for a short time. Then we do our work as soon as possible. Is it true? Or even maybe I connect wall socket ground pin to me and laptop? But there is a 1M Ohm resistance in the adaptor, so it is me directly connecting to ground, and has a 1M Ohm between me and the laptop.

Comment: Pics or it didnt happen.  That battery is McDangerous when it's inflated, so wise not to charge it.  You can rig up a static bracelet from bare copper wire tied to a local ground, but risk is drastically lowered by simple precautions like wearing cotton clothing, not sitting and standing unnecessarily and periodically touching ground, such as the cover plate screw on a properly installed electrical outlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wall is not very conductive, so it would achieve nothing.

And the point is not that you are at the same potential as the water tap is, the point is that you are in the same potential as your laptop, so that touching it does not cause a static electricity discharge.

So if you want to connect wires, it would be better to connect a wire between you and some exposed metal part on your laptop, such as the chassis of an USB connector. To limit rate of discharge and for electrical safety, generally there is a 1 megaohm resistor in the path, so the wire is not directly connected.

Comment: How about connecting to the ground pin of a wall socket?

Comment: @Superuser This only helps if the ground of the laptop is connected to that ground, too.

Comment: The point is that you and laptop and tools and perhaps even the desk are at the same potential. Whether the potential is 0V compared to building mains earth, or something else, is not that relevant in a one-off home setting. In an industrial setting, potential equalization does happen to mains earth.